# ЧТО и ТО — клитики или нет?

Tags: морфология, фонетика

Скажите, пожалуйста, являются ли слова "что" и "то" в пословице "Что посеешь, то и пожнешь" фонетическими, то есть имеющими ударения? Или они всё-таки примыкают к последующим словам?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что это самостоятельные слова с ударением. В русском языке проклитики и энклитики в основном служебные слова - предлоги, союзы, частицы. Вот фразового ударения на них нет, оно падает на сказуемые.